# How to load local image by JavaScript and convert into Base64 (I don't want to load into the browser)

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I want to load a local image file by JavaScript and convert it into Base64. I don't want to show the image in the browser.

If you have worked with Python, there is an image processing library (OpenCV) for this task. I need to do the same task, but in JavaScript.

I found the following repository in this regard:

```
https://github.com/renanbastos93/image-to-base64
```

When I run the following code, it runs without any problem.

```
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');
imageToBase64("1.jpg") // Path to the image
    .then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response); // "cGF0aC90by9maWxlLmpwZw=="
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error); // Logs an error if there was one
        }
    )
```

But, I don't want to print "response" in the console. I want to save "response" into a variable and return it. I tried the following code:

```
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');

imageToBase64("1.jpg") // Path to the image
    .then(
        (response) => {
            //console.log(response)
            var image_base64 = response; // response is Base64
            return image_base64
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error); // Logs an error if there was one
        }
    )

console.log(typeof image_base64)
```

When I run the above code, variable "image_base64" in "undefined".

I am new in JavaScript realm, and I appreciate it if you can guide me on this. When I define a function in Python, I return any desired variable. But, the above structure is totally different and I don't understand it well.

Comment: You can use `new FileReader();` api - you are do some research and will get what you are after!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command if it works for you

var image = Filereader().result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');

Comment: Thank you. How can I give image file path to the above command? Image file is saved on local PC.

Comment: Could you guide me what the "data" is?

Comment: Oh ok, the data is the name of your file. You can also insert the location of the file as opposed to data. Let me know if it works!

Comment: It gives me error: "ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined". It seems that I need to install or import it first? I am sorry that my questions are basic. I write the cod in VS Code and run it by "Node".

Comment: I think you need to use var reader = new FileReader(); and replace FileReader() with a variable like reader. Like initialize your variable as a new object of FileReader

Comment: I did it but still I get the error. I think FileReader() only works on browser.

Comment: I'll add the following answer below

Comment: @Mohammad FileReader is browser based. Not for a computer or local system. Javascript need to be run on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

//for javascript
var x = document.getElementById("myImg");

//for html

img id="myImg" src="image_location/imageName.ext"

The html code above is not the right syntax but only pseudocode.
Create a new folder where your image is. image_location is the name of that folder. You can use whatever name you want.